# Angular i18n - Error: Could not mark an element as translatable inside a translatable section

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

In my Angular 7 application, I have an html with nested tags like this -

```html
<p i18n="@@footerText">Some Text Here 
  <a i18n="@@footerLink" href="http://url.com" target="_blank">Link Text</a> 
  Another Text Here
</P>
```

When executing following command

```
ng xi18n --output-path translate
```

It throws an error -
**Error: Could not mark an element as translatable inside a translatable section**

> How to use i18n with nested tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<p>
  <ng-container i18n="@@footerPrefix">Some Text Here</ng-container> 
  <a i18n="@@footerLink" href="http://url.com" target="_blank">Link Text</a> 
  <ng-container i18n="@@footerSuffix">Another Text Here</ng-container> 
</p>
```

Or just put everything, including the link, in your translation

```
<p i18n="@@footerText">Some Text Here 
  <a href="http://url.com" target="_blank">Link Text</a> 
  Another Text Here
</p>
```